# Python 'requirements.txt' file in package

Tags: python, python-packaging, requirements.txt

**SITUATION:**

I have created a python package where I use the following libraries:

1. matplotlib
2. regex
3. statistics
4. os
5. unittest
6. coverage

my problem is that when I do `pip freeze`, the result only returns
versions values for

1. matplotlib==3.2.1
2. regex==2020.11.13
3. statistics==1.0.3.5
4. coverage==5.3.1

I have read some sites where they say that this is because, for example,
os and unittest comes already installed with Python3.X.

**QUESTION:**

1. Should I include 'os', 'unittest' in 'requirements.txt'?
2. If so, which is the version I should write?

Comment: The source you were reading is right. Os, unittest etc are already installed so you don't have to include them in reqs.txt

Comment: os and unittest are in the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html). You didn't install them via pip, so they don't need to be in the requirements file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **shouldn't** include `os` and `unittest` in `requirements.txt`.

As you read, I confirm that os and unittest are included in *Python 3.X*.

`os` and `unittest` version depends on your *Python 3.X* version.

Answer (score 2):

The source was right, you should't include os etc in your `requirements.txt`. Here is a little different problem with `pip freeze` tho - when you are not using different environments and have all the libraries in one environment, your `pip freeze` is gonna give you all the libraries you have inside and that is not helpful at all.

I'd recommend using `pipreqs` library for getting all the necessary libraries you want to put in your `requirements.txt` for your script.

```
pip install pipreqs

pipreqs /path/to/your_project
```

Comment: Note: `pipreqs` doesn't support Python 3.6+

Answer (score -3):

python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt

Comment: The question is not *how* to install the file. This is not an answer.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).